# How to include gradle project in maven

Tags: maven, gradle, release-management

I have a library (gradle project) whose release version is managed by nebula. I need to include it in a maven project. When I do a mvn release it automatically manages the project version and reverts back to the Snapshot version after the release process is done.

How do I revert the gradle project library included in maven project to the version before the release? Is there any automated way to do it ?

Comment: How is the library version affected by the release? Could you give more details?

Comment: This library is maintained by me. When the maven project is being released, this gradle project will also be released and after release will be reverted back to dev verison. Is there a way to do it automatically ?

Comment: Are you asking how to handle releasing in Gradle? Or are you asking how to update dependencies in Maven?